# Ada Both connected and use a third-party DLL library project

Tags: dll, ada

How to connect the library to the project DLL and use the procedure / function?

I have a `*.dll`, I created `*.Def` file, created `*.dll.a`, `*.ali` and `*.o`, as its use is not clear.

Set an example for the use of ...

Comment: I'm afraid we don't understand your question. What language is the interface to your DLL defined in? What is a `.dll.a` file? How did you create the `.ali` and `.o` files?

Comment: Also, are you trying to _create_ DLLs, or are you trying to _use_ DLLs?

Comment: I tried to use the DLL. 
Obtained information from the site
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Using-DLLs-with-GNAT.html

Comment: Are you getting any error when you link with the -l option or gnatlink? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do, e.g., which DLL you're linking to and if you already have the ADA Spec files for that particular DLL.

Comment: I only library test.dll and receive files def, test.def ...

Comment: If you haven't created an Ada Spec (.ads) file to interfaces with the DLL, how will you call the functions defined in test.dll? You should be able to link with something like `gnatmake main.adb -largs -ltest` nonetheless. If you're getting some sort of error then let us know

Comment: source files **dllad.dll**
after the command execution

`@echo off
dll2def dllad.dll > dllad.def
dlltool --dllname dllad.dll --def dllad.def --output-lib libdllad.a
if exist dh.o del dh.o
if exist dt.o del dt.o
if exist ds0.o del ds0.o`

received files **dllad.def libdllad.a**

after the command execution
`gnatmake main.adb -largs -ltest`

received files  **dllad.ali dllad.o dllad.exe**
what to do next I do not know.


if you do not use libdllad.a then obtained **b~dllad.adb b~dllad.ads b~dllad.ali b~dllad.o dllad.ali dllad.o**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To link with a dll you first have to know the location of the dll library in relation to the where your binary application will be on the user's computer (its file path) -- then use the pragma "Link_With".

If you wanted to link with opengl on windows you would do all of the c imports into a package spec and put something like this in the file:

```
pragma Link_With("/Windows/System32/opengl32.dll");
```